# Drone.io OAuth issues with Github

Tags: github, oauth, drone.io

I am currently trying to set up Drone.io with my Github account. I installed the drone.io and that works - I am able to get to the drone.io login page on localhost. The problem begins when I try to login to authorize access to Github, as Github returns error 404 - "This is not the page you are looking for" with the following url:

https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=%thisIsCorrect&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fauthorize&response_type=code&scope=repo+repo%3Astatus+user%3Aemail+read%3Aorg&state=drone

I tried using localhost and localhost/authorize for the Authorization Callback, but no changes. Can anyone see what am I doing incorrectly?

My Github settings:

[image]

My docker-compose file:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your authorization callback url is invalid. Instead of `http://localhost` it should be `http://localhost/authorize` per the official setup instructions.

> Register your application with GitHub to create your client id and secret. It is very import the authorization callback URL matches your http(s) scheme and hostname exactly with /authorize as the path.

Reference documentation: http://readme.drone.io/admin/setup-github/

In addition it also looks like the environment section is malformed. The environment variables in the docker-compose section should not be quoted. Docker compose does not unquote values when declared in `key=value` format.

So instead of quoting values like this:

```
environment:
  - foo='bar'
  - baz=qux
```

You should remove the quotes:

```
environment:
  - foo=bar
  - baz=qux
```

Or if you need to quote values you should use a map instead or an array in `key=value` format.

```
environment:
  foo: "bar"
  baz: qux
```

Reference docker compose documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/environment

Comment: so sorry for the late comment and thank you for your help - that has helped! :)